# How to add padding above the highest data in the chart

Tags: iwork-numbers

I have a chart that the values go to the top of the chart. Is there a way to add padding above the highest data in the chart?

[image]
In the image attached I'd like to have padding above the orange data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I just found the answer.

- Select the chart and go to the Axis tab.
- Select the Value (Y) category
- Change the max scale to a value that is slightly above the maximum value in the chart

[image]